# Not updating the State inside the function but updating in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I'm a beginner to React JS.

I faced this weird situation,

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const incrementCounter = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
    console.log(counter, "Log inside the function");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(counter, "Log inside the useEffect");
  }, [counter]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={incrementCounter}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
```

So when `incrementCounter` function is triggered counter value will be increased by 1 and right after that I'm logging the value in the console. But it displays the value as 0. When I use the `useEffect` hook to check the changes of `count` state it I'm getting the correct value as 1 when I log the count `value` inside the `useEffect` scope. What is the reason for not displaying in `incrementCounter` function and the reason for displaying the correct value inside the `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is because the `setCounter` is asynchronous.

If you use `setTimeOut` you can clearly observe it

```
setTimeout(() => {
   console.log(counter, "Log inside the function");
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

A new `incrementCounter` function object is being redefined with every render. Each time it is defined, its own internal `counter` is based on the value of `counter` state at that point. The `counter` within that particular `incrementCounter` function object is stale and doesn't get updated anymore.

Answer (score 1):

according to [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. In the rare case that you need to force the DOM update to be applied synchronously, you may wrap it in flushSync, but this may hurt performance.

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous state, read about the updater argument below.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for a clean description using my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

States value will change only after the component has rendered.

In this case the log inside the function will keep the state value even after the SetCounter, once it completes the component will render again.

The useEffect is triggered when the state has changed on such render so it shows the new value.